# Image not displaying when try to change image dynamically in react

Tags: reactjs, html5-canvas

I want to change image dynamically,In static image works fine. In dynamic when I click on **choose file** the image url displayed but image not displaying.Here is my code.

```
       {
      (this.state.imageChange==true)?(
        <canvas  id="Canvas" ref="myCanvas" width={300} height={300} />

    ):(
      <div style={{marginTop:15, marginBottom:15, marginLeft:15}}>
      </div>
    )
  }
  <input type="file" id="fileupload" name="files[]" onChange={this.fileChange.bind(this)}/>
  <input type="button" id="upload" value="Save"/>
```

I used the concept of canvas.

```
const canvas =this.refs.myCanvas;
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.fillRect(0,0, 100, 100);
var mapSprite = new Image();
mapSprite.src = this.state.pic;
```

Here is my fileChange method

```
fileChange(){
 this.setState({imageChange:true});
 var pic=document.getElementById("fileupload").files[0].name;
 this.setState({pic:pic},()=>{
    console.log("picture:"+this.state.pic);
 });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show us your `fileChange` method.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a URL for the file uploaded.

```
function handleChange(files) {
   const pic = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
   console.log(pic);
   this.setState({pic, imageChange: true});
}
```

> Another alternative is use some react libraries like [react-dropzone](https://github.com/okonet/react-dropzone) then you don't have to do all these.